# jQuery: Trying to run $.get within .each function

Tags: jquery

This code does get the index value of each element with the "profileName" class. It also does run a $.get using each index value as the url. But it fails when I try to make it put the ajax response into each element with the "details" class that is the child element of each "profilName" div. Is this doable?

```
$('.profileName').each(function(index) {
    var urlVal = $(".showProfile", this).attr('profile');
    $.get(urlVal, function(data) {
        $(".details", this).html(data);
    }, "html");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because `this` doesn't refer to what you want inside the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) `success` callback.  You can fix it by storing it beforehand, like this:

```
$('.profileName').each(function(index) {
  var urlVal = $(".showProfile", this).attr('profile'),
      details = $(".details", this);
  $.get(urlVal, function(data) {
    details.html(data); 
  }, "html" ); 
});
```

[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) uses [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) underneath, and [if a `context` option isn't specified, the ajax object itself is `this` in the callback](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L204).